How to handle Cognito Identity Provider Exceptions in Kotlin
I'm setting up Cognito using the AWS SDK (without amplify). I've noticed that when certain cases occur my try/catch Exception type does not catch AWS specific Exception types.
How do I eloquently capture all of AWS's exceptions in one catch block?
Here is some sample code below, ideally I would like to capture all Cognito specific exceptions in one block:
    AuthenticationScreenState.REGISTER_VALIDATION -> {
      try {
        // confirm account request
        confirmSignUp()

        setScreenVisibility(false)
        delay(300)

        screenStateTo(AuthenticationScreenState.VALIDATION_COMPLETE)

      }catch(e: UsernameExistsException){
        setAuthenticationErrorMessage(e.message)
      }
      catch(e: NotAuthorizedException){
        setAuthenticationErrorMessage(e.message)
      }
      catch(e: ExpiredCodeException){
        setAuthenticationErrorMessage(e.message)
      }
      catch(e: Exception){
        Log.d("Exception", e.message.toString())
        setAuthenticationErrorMessage(e.message)
      }
    }

Now, looking at their model, they have multiple exception cases that inherit from the CognitoIdentityProviderException(builder.message) . I've pasted an example of an exception snippet below.
   //Exception snippet from aws.sdk.kotlin.services.cognitoIdentityprovider -> model

  public class ExpiredCodeException private constructor(builder: Builder) : CognitoIdentityProviderException(builder.message) {

    init {
        sdkErrorMetadata.attributes[ServiceErrorMetadata.ErrorType] = ErrorType.Client
    }

    public companion object {
        public operator fun invoke(block: Builder.() -> kotlin.Unit): aws.sdk.kotlin.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.ExpiredCodeException = Builder().apply(block).build()
    }

    override fun toString(): kotlin.String = buildString {
        append("ExpiredCodeException(")
        append("message=$message")
        append(")")
    }

    override fun hashCode(): kotlin.Int {
        var result = message?.hashCode() ?: 0
        return result
    }

    override fun equals(other: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.Boolean {
        if (this === other) return true
        if (other == null || this::class != other::class) return false

        other as ExpiredCodeException

        if (message != other.message) return false

        return true
    }

    public inline fun copy(block: Builder.() -> kotlin.Unit = {}): aws.sdk.kotlin.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.ExpiredCodeException = Builder(this).apply(block).build()

    @SdkDsl
    public class Builder {
        /**
         * The message returned when the expired code exception is thrown.
         */
        public var message: kotlin.String? = null

        @PublishedApi
        internal constructor()
        @PublishedApi
        internal constructor(x: aws.sdk.kotlin.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.ExpiredCodeException) : this() {
            this.message = x.message
        }

        @PublishedApi
        internal fun build(): aws.sdk.kotlin.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.ExpiredCodeException = ExpiredCodeException(this)

        internal fun correctErrors(): Builder {
            return this
        }
    }
}

I've tried adding in this snippet, but it doesn't seem to infer the parent type of all child exceptions.
catch(e: CognitoIdentityProviderException){
  Log.d("CognitoProviderException", e.message)
  setAuthenticationErrorMessage(e.message)
}


Found a way to do this: will continue to test but  I used the following code and it seems to work.
      }catch (e: CognitoIdentityProviderException) {
        val exceptionName = e::class.simpleName
        Log.d("Exception", exceptionName.toString() + e.message)
        setAuthenticationErrorMessage("$exceptionName: ${e.message}")
      }

